# Retrieve first key of std::multimap, c++

Tags: c++, multimap

I want to retrieve just the first key of a multimap. I already achieved it with iterating through the multimap, taking the first key and then do break. But there should be a better way, but I do not find it.

```
int store_key;
std::multimap<int, int> example_map; // then something in it..
for (auto key : example_map)
{
    store_key = key;
    break;
}
```

This solves the Problem, but I am searching for another solution.

Comment: `example_map.begin()->first` ?!?

Comment: BTW, you need to consider how you'll handle the case when `example_map` is empty.

Comment: your `store_key` isnt just the key, but a `std::pair<const Key, mapped_type>`

Comment: btw this is the bad side of good abstractions like the range based for loop, obvious things get hidden. I suggest you to write your loop with a plain old iterator based loop, and you will notice how you can get rid of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range based for loop is more or less (not exactly but good enough for this answer) equivalent to:

```
for (auto it = example_map.begin(); it != example_map.end(); ++it) {
    auto key = *it;

    store_key = key;
    break;
}
```

I hope now it is clear that you can get rid of the loop and for a non-empty map it is just:

```
 auto store_key = *example_map.begin();
```

Note that `store_key` is a misnomer, because it is not just the key and your code would trigger a compiler error. It is a `std::pair<const int,int>`. `store_key->first` is the key.

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer and your comments were very useful!